# Develope Backend service for app developement using intel xdk

Tags: web-applications, intel, backend, intel-xdk

I am new to App development, What i am looking for is to create simple App which has some list . The list will be dynamically populate from some information retrieve from back-end services and contain some text and images. These images and text has to be populated or fetched from back-end server.

What i am looking for is a guide or documentation or some video to start with for creating such back-end service. What language should be preferred if i am using Intel XDK for front end development. I could not find something specific and detailed about it . Any help to start with would be much appreciated.

Comment: u can use any language for backend, as long as the backend has API endpoints that return data in JSON format, your app in XDK can access it

Comment: I believe you have contributed towards list-view template development of demo xdk app . What would you suggest , which language would be a wise yet simple to use ?

Comment: if its simple app, just use parse service, u dont have to code, it has APIs and will generate APIs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try it .